# Element of a group is its own inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $abc$ is its own inverse then so are $bca$ and $cab$.
Here's my attempt, but I don't feel very confident it's correct:

$$\begin{eqnarray}(abc)(abc) &=& e \\
a^{-1}a(bca)bc &=& a^{-1}e \\
e(bca)bc &=& a^{-1}\\
(bca)bcc^{-1} &=&a^{-1}c^{-1}\\
(bca)be&=&a^{-1}c^{-1}\\
(bca)bb^{-1}&=&a^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1}\\
(bca)e&=&a^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1}\\
bca &=& a^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1}\\
(bca)^{-1} &=& a^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1}\\
(bca)(bca)^{-1} &=& a^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1} bca\end{eqnarray}$$
The second part would be pretty much similar

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: You can do it a bit more quickly by doing this: $(abc)(abc) = e \implies a^{-1}(abc)(abc)a = a^{-1} e a \implies bcabca = e$. (The operation $x \mapsto a^{-1} x a$ is called *conjugation*, and it has many interesting properties.)

Answer (score 2):

A direct proof:

$(bca)(bca)=(bca)(bca)(bc)(bc)^{-1}=(bc)(abc)(abc)(bc)^{-1}=e$

$(cab)(cab)=(cab)(cab)(c)(c)^{-1}=(c)(abc)(abc)(c)^{-1}=e$

Answer (score 1):

All the elements you mention are conjugated. And conjugates have the same order. Being its own inverse means its order is at most 2.